# How can i use the same watcher (Subscription) for several components in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscription

In an Angular application,
I need for user preferences change to save in the database (by back api).
This code should be use in all pages (components).

I got this code :

```
export class OneComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    
    watcherSubscriptionForUser: Subscription = Subscription.EMPTY;
    
    async ngOnInit() {
        this.watcherSubscriptionForUser = this.libUserService.data.subscribe((currentUser: UserItem) => {
                // Preferences changed => call api to save data
            });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.watcherSubscriptionForUser.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

I did not manage to use `Subscription` inside a service.
How can I factorize this peace of code to use for all my concerned components?

Comment: would you consider doing the subscription from the service? (seems to be right object to have it, as it contains the `data`variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want to use service, then do this.

Create a Base Class like below :-

```
// Remove @Directive if you are using angular < v9.
@Directive()
export class BaseWatcherClass {
  watcherSubscriptionForUser: Subscription = Subscription.EMPTY;
  libUserService;
  constructor(service) {
    this.libUserService = service;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
      this.watcherSubscriptionForUser = this.libUserService.data.subscribe((currentUser: UserItem) => {
         // Preferences changed => call api to save data
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
     this.watcherSubscriptionForUser.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Then extend this class :-

```
export class OneComponent extends BaseWatcherClass implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   constructor(libUserService) {
     super(libUserService)
   }

   ngOnInit() {
     // other piece of code, this ngOnInit is only required if you want to have some other logic with default one else you can skip it.

    super.ngOnInit();
   }
}
```

Comment: I can use in a service, but I did not find how to do this. Can I a solution with service as well. I did not  manage to insert watcher in a shared service... How can I do this ?

Comment: even in that case you will be needing a service instance per component, after re iterating your problem the solution i have given above suits best.

Comment: I will test your solution with inheritance.